# Sublime text regex - remove text in parenthesizes

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, wildcard

I am having list on telephone numbers in my js file, and some of them have in parenthesizes translations that I don't need:

```
Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)
```

I wont to find regex in sublime to do that, but I cannot find the right command. I have tried:

```
((.))

((*))

\(.*)\

\(.*\)
```

But I aways remove something different ... If someone know the solution, please help.

Comment: can you show some samples?

Comment: Your last choice Works fine for me if you replace the match with nothing.

Comment: It removes all the file after (.....

Comment: I see what is the problem ... I will write an answer but thank you Poul Bak

Answer (score 0):

Ok as Paul Bak said the (.*) works at his computer, and it does work, just that my js file is compressed all in same line so it removes everything after the (...

I beautified js and use this regex and now it is solved.